# why momentjs isBetween function is not behaving as expected for the year 2020

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The followings return true

```
moment('2019-11-15').isBetween('2019-11-15', undefined, null, '[]');
moment('2016-10-25').isBetween('2016-10-25', undefined, null, '[]');
```

But this one returns false

```
moment('2020-11-15').isBetween('2020-11-15', undefined, null, '[]');
```

Do i miss something for the year 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment('2020-11-15').isBetween('2020-11-15', undefined, null, '[]');
```

This one returns false because the order of the 2 dates.
Above command means you are checking if `targetDate >= 2020-11-15 && targetDate <= today(2020-11-05)` which is always false until 2020/11/15

since moment(undefined) evaluates as moment() which is the current date, you need to change the 1st and 2nd argument.

---

```
// date `A` should be always earlier date than date `B`
moment('2020-11-15').isBetween(A, B, C, D);
```